# JS / TS must use bind but still need original this

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, closures, bind

I am not sure how to approach this user interaction problem I have. 
API is [3DMol](http://3dmol.csb.pitt.edu/doc/$3Dmol.GLModel.html#setClickable)

I am trying to access both `this` elements in

```
model.setClickable({chain: theChain, resi: mappedPosition}, true, function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

First of all, for the original implementation as above `this` would be a location the user clicked on. However, I as well need to combine the clicked location with some value from the calling object outside.

I tried `.bind(null,this)` yet within the function `this` is set to `null`.

I tried a closure

```
const clickClosure = function(){

    const mutations = self.alignment.mutations;

    function clicker(){
        console.log(this);
        console.log(mutations);
    }

    return clicker();
} 

model.setClickable({chain: theChain, resi: mappedPosition}, true,clickClosure);
```

to find that mutations existed, but `this` was not defined. Any idea how to get both without using global variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda function to pass down a lexical `this`.

```
model.setClickable({chain: theChain, resi: mappedPosition}, true, (stuff) => {
    console.log(this, stuff); // no `this` binding to the function
});
```

That should keep `this` bound to the caller, and it's really the only way to get that reference from a callback like this.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot the lambda notation => It works now